# SQLite3 WHERE clause doesn't return anything if datatype is BLOB

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24 3d862f207e3adc00f78066799ac5a8c282430a5f on Ubuntu 16.04

The query `SELECT * FROM wordlist WHERE term like 'juliet'` doesn't seem to return anything while the query `SELECT * FROM wordlist WHERE cast(term as text) like 'juliet'` returns as it should.

The datatype of the `term` column is `blob` which is also strange since I defined it as TEXT.

The problem doesn't occur in SQLite 3.8.10.2

Comment: Does it still occur in 3.13?

Comment: What is the actual table definition? What is the output of `SELECT typeof(term) FROM wordlist WHERE cast(term as text) like 'juliet'`?